# right way to use eval statement in pandas dataframe map function

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, eval

I have a pandas dataframe where one column is 'organization', and the content of such column is a string with a list inside the string :

```
data['organization'][0]
Out[6] "['loony tunes']"

data['organization'][1]
Out[7] "['the three stooges']"
```

I want to substitute the string with the list which is inside the string. I try to use map, where the function inside map is eval:

```
data['organization'] = data['organization'].map(eval)
```

But the what I get is is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-   packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-3dbc0abf8c2e>", line 1, in <module>
    data['organization'] = data['organization'].map(eval)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2015, in map
    mapped = map_f(values, arg)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1046, in pandas.lib.map_infer     (pandas\lib.c:56983)
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

Thus I resorted to the following block of code, which is extremely inefficient:

```
for index, line in data['organization'].iteritems():
    print(index)
    if type(line) != str:
        data['organization'][index] = []
    try:
        data['organization'][index] = eval(data['organization'][index])
    except:
        continue
```

What am I doing wrong? how can I use eval (or a vectorized implementation) instead of the clumsy loop above?

I thought the problem might be that some elements in pd.series data['organization'] are not strings, so I implemented the following:

```
def is_string(x):
    if type(x) != str:
        x = ''

data['organization'] = data['organization'].map(is_string)
```

But I still get the same error when I try:

```
data['organization'] = data['organization'].map(eval)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use "apply" instead of "map"

Comment: Anzel: thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately, I get the same output with "apply".

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong other than this function.

Comment: Either your data['organization'] has noisy values (NOT string), can you confirm?

Comment: Anzel, you are right. but the is_string function should take care of that. after I do map(is_string), the pd.series should only include strings.

Comment: That is out of this question scope, but if you have mixed types both non-evaluate and evaluated, then do a map or apply with a function and perform a try/except then you should be good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using eval is generally frowned upon as it **allows arbitrary python code to be run**. So you should **strongly** prefer not to use it if possible.

In this case, you don't need to evaluate an expression, you just need to parse the value. This means that you can use ast's [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["['loony tunes']", "['the three stooges']"])

In [12]: from ast import literal_eval

In [13]: s.apply(literal_eval)
Out[13]:
0          [loony tunes]
1    [the three stooges]
dtype: object

In [14]: s.apply(literal_eval)[0]  # look, it works!
Out[14]: ['loony tunes']
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> ```
> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
> ```
>
> *Safely* evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: I agree with **literal_eval** for safer measures, although OP's error is probably due to mixed types of both evaluated and non-evaluated strings -- OP's original approach with just "eval" doesn't work neither.

Comment: @Anzel good point. Wrapping this in a try/except (for each literal_eval call) is the workaround. Though finding the underlying case is worthwhile.

Comment: Anzel: you were right, error was due to mixed types (actually nans). after filling nans with a string, literal_eval did a nice job.

Comment: Andy, thanks a lot. literal_eval did solve the problem. I guess that, as a non expert, I still fight a bit with the notion of apply vs map. After filing the nans with strings (data['organization'] = data['organization'].fillna('[]'), both apply and map on literal_eval did the job. But when is one is one preferable to the other?

Comment: btw, I know that map vs. apply is a complete different question, do not feel the need to reply it. I will some do some research on it.